# error TS2345: Argument of type 'StateType' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ demo_state?: { demo_state: { title: string; }; }; }'

Tags: typescript

**FIXED**: So the problem was in my reducer `demo_state.ts`, particularly at `state = initState`. I changed it to `state = initState.demo_state` it works.

```
import {initState} from '../initState';

const demo_state = (state = initState.demo_state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default demo_state;
```

---

**ORIGINAL**:
I am new to TypeScript. I integrated TypeScript to React/Redux and currently I have an error in TypeScript that I don't know how to solve it.

I created a file name `StateType.d.ts`:

```
interface DemoState {
  title: string
}

export interface StateType {
  demo_state: DemoState
}
```

And file `initState.ts`(this file holds our app's initial state)

```
import {StateType} from './type/StateType';

export const initState: StateType = {
    demo_state: {
        title: "Hello World"
    }
}
```

At last, the `initState.ts` file is imported to `client.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
// API from redux createStore(<reducer>)
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
// Component from react-redux help share store to all container components
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// Import the reducer function with arbitrary name
import rootReducer from './reducers';
// Import thunk
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
// Import redux logger
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
// Root State for App
import { initState } from './initState';

//const middlewares = [ thunk ];
const middlewares = [ thunk, createLogger() ]; 

const appStore = createStore(rootReducer, initState, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={ appStore }>
    <App />
</Provider>, 
document.getElementById('app'));
```

My Type script command is as follow:

```
"scripts": {
    "type-check-client": "tsc -p ./src/client/tsconfig.json || true",
},
```

When I run `npm run type-check-client`, I receive the following error:

```
src/client/client.tsx(20,43): error TS2345: Argument of type 'StateType' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ demo_state?: { demo_state: { title: string; }; }; }'.
  Types of property 'demo_state' are incompatible.
    Property 'demo_state' is missing in type 'DemoState' but required in type '{ demo_state: { title: string; }; }'.
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong here? I would truly appreciate any help out there.

**PS**: I enclosed my reducer here

- First file: `demo_state.ts`

```
import {initState} from '../initState';
import {StateType} from '../type/StateType';

const demo_state = (state = initState, action: any): StateType => {
    switch (action.type) {

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default demo_state;
```

- Second file: `index.ts`

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import demo_state from './demo_state';

export default combineReducers({
    demo_state
    //another_state_prop,
})
```

Comment: search your codebase for `demo_state?`. my guess is your `rootReducer` has a type definition with an optional `demo_state` because `demo_state` is undefined at first and then loaded when you call createStore. can you post your `reducers.ts` file?

Comment: What's your reducer look like?

Comment: I just enclosed my reducer in my question above, please take a look